# Memory consumption by "svchost.exe -k netsvcs" on Windows 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, svchost

We have a number of servers (Windows 2008 R2 SP1) with "svchost.exe -k netsvcs" regularly occupying ~1Gb of memory and that's too much. All servers are primarily application servers w/o IIS or MS SQL installed.

I'm just wondering where do I start looking? I'm aware of pre-SP1 WMI memory leak but all my servers have SP1 installed.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/586407/svchost-exe-k-netsvcs-occupying-1gb-memory Are you guys coworkers or something?

Comment: Yep, looks like the same problem but no we're not co-workers. At least it proves I'm not crazy :)